# How can I display another DIV while the ajax is processing and the request is not completed yet?

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-ajax

There are two Div : `contentDiv` and `progressDiv`. I am using ajax to submit data in the following way. 
For ajax completion, it can take a lot of time because I am using ajax to upload different data, including multiple images so it can take upto 15 20 seconds for ajax to complete.

While ajax is on progress, I would like to display `progressDiv` to the user indicating that submission is going on. I tried to keep showing and hiding divs in different places like just on function call, `beforeSend` ajax function, on success, on error, but problem is that `progressDiv` doesn't show and contentDiv does not hide.

**What changes should I make so that while ajax is on processing, it shows `progressDiv` to the user ?**

```
 function submitButtonClick() {
        // on button click I inserted timeout function to hide contentDiv and show 
        // progressDiv but these codes don't execute

        setTimeout(function () {
            document.getElementById("progressDiv").style.display = "block";
            document.getElementById("contentDiv").style.display = "none";
        }, 400);

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "Home/SubmitData",
            data: formdata,
            async: false,
            cache: false,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
               // on beforeSend function also, I inserted timeout function to hide contentDiv and show 
               // progressDiv but these codes don't execute
            beforeSend: function (xhr, status) {
                document.getElementById("progressDiv").style.display = "block";
                document.getElementById("contentDiv").style.display = "none";
            },
            success: function (xhr) {
                if (xhr.success == true) {
                    setTimeout(function () {
                        document.getElementById("progressDiv").style.display = "none";
                    }, 1500);

                    alert(xhr.messsage);
                    window.location.href = '@Url.Action("Index", "Home")';
                } else {
                    document.getElementById("progressDiv").style.display = "none";
                    document.getElementById("contentDiv").style.display = "block";
                }
            },
            error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                setTimeout(function () {
                    document.getElementById("myprogress1").style.display = "none";
                    document.getElementById("mainwizard").style.display = "block";
                }, 1500);

                alert('Sorry! Error occured while saving data');
            }
        });
   }
```

Comment: you have set window.location.href to home page on success, in you page sending ajax data to SubmitData page takes few seconds right, so u want be able to see the progressDiv displaying....

Comment: put the "window.location.href = '@Url.Action("Index", "Home")';" in the setTimeout function and see what happens

Comment: you can be using a complete function or send a callback function as a parameter